# Prevent interruptions in ms-word

Tags: c#, loops, ms-word

I have a loop which is iterating through words in a word document, but the problem is that a popup shows up that prevents the loop from continuing.

[image: popup that messes up code]

^^Is saying the office version is not activated.
It will then give the following error

```
COM Exception: Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))
```

I have tried looking through the page class in an effort to find something, but had no luck.

I am using a for loop.

```
                for (int x = 1; x <= doc.Words.Count - 1; x++) //doc is already set
                {
                     //do what I want
                }
```

**A better question**
How do I find an already opened ms-word application.
I have tried having one open and looking through all the processes and casting it to word.Application, but it didn't work...

Comment: I don't understand why you asked this using `c#` and `loops` tags? Even I'm not sure this should belongs Stackoverflow.

Comment: I need a way to prevent the microsoft popup with c#, I will post some more of my code.

Comment: register your office version and the pop-up will go away :D

Comment: @ismellike there is no way to suppress this popup with C#.  The office version believes itself to be unregistered and will not correctly function until this is resolved

Comment: you want to suppress microsoft product with microsoft product? :D